# How can I install a monorepo package from a concrete branch via npm

Tags: git, npm

I have a monorepo with several packages inside. And I can install each of them directly via npm install - because they get published.

But how can I install this from a specific branch in the monorepo? ... Is it possible at all?

(The use case is that I want to test a change in one of the packages, which is a dependency of my main project - but without the need to merge my change in the monorepo master and update the version in in my main project ... cause this package in the monorepo will affect a lot of projects in the company.)